# Installing extension postgresql 9.4 for all schemes

Tags: postgresql

How to install an extension pg_stat_statements once for all schemes in a single database postgresql 9.4?

```
CREATE EXTENSIONS pg_stat_statements;
```

installs only in the public schema

**UPD:**
I solved the problem as follows:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d "template1" -c "CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d "template1" -c "ALTER EXTENSION pg_stat_statements SET SCHEMA pg_catalog;"
```

The newly created database will have an extension in pg_catalog scheme that will allow this extension to work with all other schemes in the database.

Comment: An extension is not installed "per schema", it is installed per database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the extension yes, but this extension generates special views that *are* bound to a schema.

Answer (score 0):

As given [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html#AEN65375), although the Extension installs in Public by default, you can change and install it on any Schema using the given syntax.

From your question it seems that you need to install the extension in all Schemas.... Please note that you don't need to install a given Extension in all Schemas (within a Database). The Schema is just a placeholder for all the DB objects, but once installed, the Extension as such, is available to all Schemas in the Database (and needn't be installed for each Schema).

Comment: The default is not `public` but *If not specified, and the extension's control file does not specify a schema either, the current default object creation schema is used.* (which is the first valid entry of `search_path`)